# Recalculate SlickGrid grouping aggregator totals for only one column

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

If a grouping aggregator is defined for an editable column, when an edit for that column is committed, by default the grouping total for that column does not update.

In the following code sample, I can call `dataView.refresh()` whenever an edit is commited for a certain column, but this will recalculate the grouping aggregator totals for **all** the columns with grouping aggregators.

```
grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    var dataView = grid.getData();
    var column = grid.getColumns()[args.cell];
    if (column.id === 'MyEditableColumn') {
        dataView.refresh();
    }
});
```

For thousands of data items and many grouping aggregators, this could be computationally heavy in older browsers, especially if it's going to happen after every edit in a column with a grouping aggregator. Is there a way to recalculate a single grouping aggregator for only **one** column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you're using a DataView, you should be notifying it of an update on that particular item:

```
grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function (e, args) {
  dataView.updateItem(args.item.id, args.item);
});
```

Now, the way it's implemented right now, it will result in a full recalculation (and not just the aggregators - filter, groups, etc.; all of that may have changed due to a change in the item!), which is usually fast enough for at least 50'000 rows in even older browsers.  Restricting the recalc to just a particular column change is not going to work.

Comment: Thanks. `dataView.updateItem()` instead of `dataView.refresh()` does make me feel better. :)

Comment: by viewing source code, dataView.updateItem uses refresh internally